# Mass Renaming (Adding Suffix/Prefix) of files recursively in Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, recursion, command-line-interface, file-rename

I have a folder with many sub-folders which have further sub-folders. each folder has a number of files.

I want to rename all the file by adding some suffix to them

for ex:
 Original: FileName1.ext
        Final   : Suf_FileName1.ext

To carry out this function, found this command online

```
 `FOR /R %x IN (*) DO ren "%x" Suf_*`
```

but this replaces the initial characters in the original file name
like
     Original: FileName1.ext
      Final  : Suf_Name.ext

(please note it has removed initial characters in the initial file name )

Please suggest changes/modifications in the above command, 
or another command to carry out the function.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: here are few [ways](http://www.howtogeek.com/111859/how-to-batch-rename-files-in-windows-4-ways-to-rename-multiple-files/)

Comment: based on below answer `FOR /R %x IN (*) DO ren  "%x"  "Suf_%~nxx"`

Answer (score 3):

When you use a `for` command to iterate over a set of files, the `for` replaceable parameter (`%x` in your sample) contains a reference to the file.

When you use `%x` in the commands contained in the `do` clause, this parameter is replaced by information of the file being processed, by default the name and extension of the file (when using a simple `for`) or the file with full path (when using a recursive `for /R`), but you can decide and changee what information you want to use. The replaceable parameter allows the usage of some modifiers (you can see the full list if you execute `for /?`)

In your case, for your rename mask you need the name and extension of the file being referenced (I've changed your `%x` with `%F` so the syntax is clearer)

```
%~nxF
 ^^^^.... replaceable parameter
 ||+..... extension of the file referenced
 |+...... name of the file referenced
 +....... operator for modifier usage
```

Your command could be something like

```
for /R %F in (*) do echo ren "%F" "Suf_%~nxF"
```

- ***note***: The `echo` in the command is just a debugging habit. Before changing anything, first show to console the commands that will be executed. If the output seems correct then we only have to remove the `echo` and run the command again.

Remember that if you want to use the command inside a batch file, you need to escape the percent signs in the `for` replaceable parameters by doubling them. Inside a batch file the previous command will be

```
for /R %%F in (*) do echo ren "%%F" "Suf_%%~nxF"
```

Comment: Thank you very much Brother. !!